# find and sed did not replace file content

Tags: sed, find

I tried to use `find -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i.bak 's|"$_SERVER[\"DOCUMENT_ROOT\"]./|$_SERVER[\"DOCUMENT_ROOT\"]."/|gI' {} \;` to replace

```
<?php
include("$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]./info/benth_nav_top.php");
include_once("$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]./analyticstracking.php");
?>
```

to

```
<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/info/benth_nav_top.php");
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/analyticstracking.php");
?>
```

Unfortunately, it did not replace anything.

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `[...]` in regexes is special, `"` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You want to move the double quote from before `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].` to after it.

The `sed` command to do that in a single file:

```
sed 's/"\(\$_SERVER\["DOCUMENT_ROOT"\]\.\)/\1"/' file.php
```

The `$`, `[`, `]` and `.` are special in the pattern and has to be escaped (this is the main issue in your code).  The expression above captures the part of the string that we want to stay unchanged and replaces it with the same string, but with a `"` inserted afterwards.

Add `g` after `s/.../.../` to make the change for all the occurrences of the pattern on each line.

To run this on all `.php` files in or under the current directory:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' \
    -exec sed -i.bak 's/"\(\$_SERVER\["DOCUMENT_ROOT"\]\.\)/\1"/' {} ';'
```